# Rails 3, how to get the value of select tag item with dynamic parameter name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters

how do I get the selected value of this select_tag, here is my code
There are multiple forms like these on one page, thats why I use "dropdown_cases#{e.id}"

```
<%= form_tag "/application/cart", :remote => true do %>
   <%= select_tag "dropdown_cases#{e.id}", options_for_select([ ["6 Bottles", 1], ["12 Bottles", 2], ["18 Bottles", 3], ["24 Bottles", 4], ["30 Bottles", 5], ["36 Bottles", 6], ["42 Bottles", 7]]) %>
   <%= image_submit_tag("/images/none.png", :class => "add_to_cart_submit", :onclick => "add_to_cart_notify(#{e.id});") %>
<% end %>
```

Lets say the id here is 123 for instance
Now my question is how do I access this value `params[:dropdown_cases123]`

---

Thanks Joe Pym for the awnser! I would just like to post my findings for future refrence or for other users with the same problem.

---

**view**

```
<% @results_all.each do |e| %>
 <%= form_tag "/application/cart", :remote => true do %>
  <%= select_tag "dropdown_cases[]", options_for_select([ ["6 Bottles", 1], ["12 Bottles", 2], ["18 Bottles", 3], ["24 Bottles", 4], ["30 Bottles", 5], ["36 Bottles", 6], ["42 Bottles", 7]]) %>
  <%= image_submit_tag("/images/none.png", :class => "add_to_cart_submit" %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**controller**

```
params["dropdown_cases"].each do |cases|
 @this_is_the_dropdown_value = cases.to_i
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use square brackets.

```
select_tag "dropdown_cases[]", options_for ....
```

Note the []. Rails will then store this as {"dropdown_cases" => [one option for each form]}.

If it's important to know which select provided which value, you can nest them, so

```
select_tag "dropdown_cases[bob]", ...
```

will provide {"dropdown_cases" => {"bob" => selected_option}}.

Basically, [] stores it in an array, and [key] stores it in a hash with that key.

Comment: would it be possible for you to post a snippet from the view file and the controller?

Comment: In your example, replace "dropdown_cases#{e.id}" with "dropdown_cases[]", then in the controller, access it with params["dropdown_cases"], which should be an array of the various selects on the page.

Comment: Any idea how I can pass this value to javascript when the user selects a diffirent value from the dropdown? eg. `<%= select_tag "dropdown_cases[]", options_for_select([ ["6 Bottles", 1], ["12 Bottles", 2], ["18 Bottles", 3], ["24 Bottles", 4], ["30 Bottles", 5], ["36 Bottles", 6], ["42 Bottles", 7]]), :onchange => "update_price();" %>` How do I get this value to the **update_price** function?

Comment: If you are using rails 3, you should have jquery. Use $('#dropdown_cases').val() (or some class etc you've set on the select) to grab what's selected. Looking at your exact code, you could try passing this into the onchange? 

    :onchange => "update_price(this);"